# Updating excel sheet using Apache POI with ArrayList

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

I have to update an existing excel sheet to capture the results. The results should be added in my excel sheet at specific rows rather than sequentially.
The values are provided in ArrayList but the last index only being added in the excel sheet. Below is the code:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> writeResult(String filename, ArrayList<String> code, ArrayList<String> value) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(filename);
    Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("DataSheet-Execution");
    String statusString="";
    int count = 0;
    Row row=sh.getRow(5);   


    for(int k=0;k<code.size();k++){
        for(int j=5;j<=28;j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=row.getLastCellNum();i++)
            {
                if(row.getCell(i) != null)
                {           
                    row = sh.getRow(j);         
                    Cell status=row.getCell(4); 
                    statusString = status.toString();
                    if(statusString.equals("Y"))
                    {       
                        Cell cellxAction=row.createCell(26);
                        Cell cellRes=row.createCell(27);

                        cellxAction.setCellValue(code.get(k).toString());
                        cellRes.setCellValue(value.get(k).toString());

                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(filename);
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Excel File Written");       
    return value;
}
```

Comment: what are hardcoded values `26` and `27`?

Comment: @Jobin they are columns that were created for writing the results

Comment: Did you try debugging?